# How to run specific WSL2 distro with Ubuntu.exe app?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-distributions

I have been looking for a good solution having multiple instances of WSL2 Ubuntu installed. I am able to do that from `cmd` but I really like the Ubuntu application app and its visuals.

There are several alternatives, whereas I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51691577/12374737) post and answer which seemed like a great solution as it copies the `ubuntu.exe` file. Unfortunately this did not work as expected as the distros won't run after changing the `DistroName` as per [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51691577/12374737).

I manage to create multiple distros as the `wsl -l` command shows. But I do not manage to run them separately with the `ubuntu.exe` files.

Do you have a good solution for running a specific ubuntu distro with the `Ubuntu.exe` app/window?

Comment: You can run a specific distribution with `wsl.exe -d <distro>` command.

Comment: @Biswapriyo While the OP didn't say it explicitly, they mention that they are able to launch multiple distros from `cmd`, so I assume that `wsl -d` is being used for this.  The question is how they can get the same *terminal* look-and-feel when they use CMD/wsl that `ubuntu.exe` launches.

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:*  The console that you see when you start the default distro with `ubuntu.exe` and the one you see by running `wsl -d <otherUbuntuDistro>` *should* be the same.  They are both using the legacy Windows Console.  Really, any command that does console/terminal output in Windows (at least in Windows 10), uses this.

You should be able to see this by clicking on the top-left icon for each Windows and select Properties.  You should see that the config dialog for both is the same.

There are some minor differences in the way they are *configured* by default, it seems.  For instance, on my system (which should be default), the CMD defaults to "Courier New", but the one launched by Ubuntu uses Consolas.  Really, though, that's the only difference that I see, other than the Ubuntu icon displaying in the titlebar.

---

*More Detail:*

As far as actually using `ubuntu.exe` executable for launching a distro that you `wsl --import`ed, probably not.

`ubuntu.exe` is what's known as an "App Execution Alias" -- it's a pointer to the App Store installation.  You'll find it if you go to Windows Settings, in the "Manage app execution aliases" area.

You can also see its location from PowerShell with `(Get-Command ubuntu.exe).path`.  If you examine *this* location (`get-childitem (split-path -parent (get-command ubuntu.exe).path)`), you'll see that Windows manages these as symlinks to the actual Package directory.

`wsl.exe` really is the replacement command, since it can handle any distro that you have installed, as it seems you've already determined.

But better yet, in my opinion, is to simply use the new Windows Terminal for launching and managing all your terminal sessions (all WSL instance, CMD, PowerShell, and more).  Windows Terminal is:

- A modern, tab-based terminal, ultimately meant to replace the legacy Windows Console
- A Microsoft project
- Feature rich
- Under active development with regular new releases and features
- Fully open-source ([Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal))
- Planned to be usable as the default terminal (replacing Windows Console) in Windows 11, although whether or not this feature is stable at launch is still TBD afaik.
- Has hilarious [release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases).

One of the great features is that Windows Terminal will automatically detect all of your WSL instances and add menu entries/profiles for them (using `wsl -d <distroname>`).  So each of your Ubuntu distros will show up as separate profiles.  If you add another (or delete one), Windows Terminal will pick it up the next time it is launched.